# Xen DomU ethernet driver seems not loading

Tags: xen

**Problem**

The Ethernet virtual device of my DomU **doesn't seems to load** and I can't explain why.

**Context**

***Dom0 Info***

Dom0 : Debian Wheezy with Xen

```
uname -r : 3.2.0-4-amd64
```

Dom0 dmesg

```
[11:55]root@Dopamine2:~[0]# dmesg | grep Network
[   11.550947] Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Driver - version 3.2.10-k
[   11.627242] igb 0000:03:00.0: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Connection
[   11.705513] igb 0000:03:00.1: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Connection
```

Dom0 lspci

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
03:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
```

***One Working DomU***

I have 1 x fresh DomU (wheezy), installed with "xen-create-image", working perfectly.
When I do a dmesg on this DomU, we can see inside : "Initialising Xen virtual ethernet driver"

***Failing DomU (the problem)***

But another existing DomU (that I want to migrate from an old Dom0 to the new one), also a Debian wheezy, seems to be not working. Network is not loaded :

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
[warn] Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not re-enable some interfaces ... (warning).
[....] Reconfiguring network interfaces...Cannot find device "eth0"
Failed to bring up eth0.
```

When I do a  dmesg on this failing box, the "Initialising Xen virtual ethernet driver" is NOT inside.

(I don't know what other information I can provide ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to load some missing modules in your guest

Try `lsmod | grep xen` in your working guest and failing guest and compare them. If you see a difference, try to load this module in your Dom0 `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` and update the initramfs

**I suspect that you should load the `xen_netfront` module.**

***Add the missing module***

```
echo xen_netfront >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
```

***Update initramfs***

```
cd /tmp
mkinitramfs $(uname -r) -o /tmp/initrd-$(uname -r) 
cp /tmp/initrd-$(uname -r) /boot/initrd-$(uname -r)
```

This is the file you should load in your `/etc/xen/your-guest.cfg`

For example `ramdisk     = '/boot/initrd-3.2.0-4-amd64'`

***Then shutdown and re-create the failing guest***

```
xm shutdown guest
xm create guest.cfg
```

And check the result.